# linux programming: write to device file

Tags: c, linux

I wrote this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <mtd/mtd-user.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main( void )
{
        int fd;
        char buf[4]="abc";

        fd = open("/dev/mtd0", O_RDWR);
        lseek(fd, 1, SEEK_SET);
        write(fd, &buf, 4);
        close(fd);
        perror("perror output:");

        return 0;
}
```

The file /dev/mtd0 is created using nandsim kernel module, and run

```
mtdinfo /dev/mtd0
```

got meaningful output.After i run my program, it's output:

```
perror output:: Invalid argument
```

If there is any error in my program?

Comment: Your error reporting is wrong. You need to check the return value of each individual system call/library function, and use `perror` _right after_ a _failed_ call, with no intervening function call. As written, the `perror` call you have doesn't give you any information at all.

Answer (score 2):

You should have something like this

```
if(-1 == write(fd, &buf, 4)){
  perror("perror output:");
}
close(fd);
```

because perror shows last error.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/perror/

and more about perror http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=597

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a problem. Your use of `perror()` is wrong.

You should first check if a system call indicates a problem before calling perror.
The man page is quite explicit on the subject:

```
Note that errno is undefined after a successful library call: this call
may  well  change  this  variable, even though it succeeds, for example
because it internally used some other  library  function  that  failed.
Thus,  if  a failing call is not immediately followed by a call to per‐
ror(), the value of errno should be saved.
```

You should be checking the return codes of each system, and only call perror if they fail.
Something like this:

```
fd = open("/dev/mtd0", O_RDWR);
if (fd < 0) {
    perror("open: ");
    return 1;
}
if (lseek(fd, 1, SEEK_SET) < 0) {
    perror("lseek: ");
    return 1;
}
if (write(fd, &buf, 4) < 0) {
    perror("write: ");
    return 1;
}
close(fd);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps ?

http://forums.freescale.com/t5/Other-Microcontrollers/Can-t-write-new-uboot-to-mtd0-in-linux-on-MPC8313E-RDB/td-p/34727

It all has to deal with access rights.

And as Jakub and Mat say, check the error code for each API call.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to write an entire page and not only 4 bytes.

You can confirm this by typing the command `dmesg` in shell. 
Then you should see the following Kernel message:

> nand_do_write_ops: Attempt to write not page aligned data

Then replace the code to write in the mtd by:

```
char buf[2048]="abcdefghij";                      //Ajust size according to 
                                                  //mtd_info.writesize
mtd_info_t mtd_info;                              // the MTD structure

if (ioctl(fd, MEMGETINFO, &mtd_info) != 0) {...   // get the device info

memset(buf+10, 0xff, mtd_info.writesize - 10);    //Complete buf with 0xff's

if (write(fd, &buf, mtd_info.writesize) < 0) {... // write page
```

Also consider to check bad blocks (`ioctl(fd, MEMGETBADBLOCK, ...`) and erase blocks (`ioctl(fd, MEMERASE, ...`) before you write.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is in this line:

```
if (write(fd, &buf, 4) < 0) {
```

The second parameter to the write call has to be a pointer, "buf" is already a pointer, referencing it with the "&" you obtain a pointer to a pointer that is wrong: the correct call is:

```
if (write(fd, (void*)buf, 4) < 0) {
```

Comment: In C, for arrays that are on the stack, `&buf` and `&buf[0]` ends up with the same address, so it's not the source of the error (though it's still something that should be corrected).